# Filter By Owner in list views Not working

Tags: custom-object, list-view, master-detail, ownership

I am facing this issue and I can't seem to find any solution. I have a custom object, **Subscription**
 and I want to control the **list views**. If I create a list view with **All Subsctiption Details**, I can see the records created by all users.

But if I create a new list view, Specify Filter Criteria-->Filter By Owner--> **My Subsctiption Details** and  I create new records from the button in the list view, I'm unable to see any records created by me!
Following is a screention of the list view setup of my object Subscription.

[image: List view]

There is no Role setup in the org, but there is territory. My custom object share a MD relation with Account.

Am I missing anything? Please guide, Thanks

Comment: could be a silly suggestion, but this happens all time with some of my users,are you sure you are looking at "All" in the list that shows up once you save the view. Sometimes I click on a specific letter on the pagination and when the new view is created it still points to the letter "e" or "a" and when I click "All" it shows all the records.

Comment: Thnx for your comment @rao. I double checked after ur comment ;-) .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From SF:

> The Owner field on the detail object is not available and is
>   automatically set to the owner of its associated master record. Custom
>   objects on the detail side of a master-detail relationship cannot have
>   sharing rules, manual sharing, or queues, as these require the Owner
>   field.

So if you've been adding subscription records to an Account that someone else owns, the Subscription record will default to them as the owner, which means it wouldn't show up in your list view.

Comment: good point missed the MD relation reference at the end of the question.

Comment: Baiscs of m-d! Thnx